# Should StringBuilder.append() be always preferred than concatenation?

Tags: java, concatenation, stringbuilder

I have some code like this:

```
StringBuilder rgba = new StringBuilder();  
for (...){
....
rgba.append(value + ", ");
}
```

`IntelliJ` shows me the following warning:

```
string concatenation as argument to 'stringbuilder.append()' call
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43108059/warning-in-stringbuffer-and-stringbuilder), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817951/string-concatenation-in-java-when-to-use-stringbuilder-and-concat) and other sources I understand that concatenation is actually creates a new String object and that negates the whole point of using a `StringBuilder`.
So `IntelliJ`suggests me to use

```
rgba.append(value);
rgba.append(", ");
```

instead of

```
rgba.append(value + ", ");
```

But will this really be better?
Will this code be clearer?
Will this make the execution faster?

Comment: frankly, for this particular scenario I wouldn't give a second thought about "what is better" (how better? by which metric?). Concerning clearer, I would say "agree with Intellij" here, as you already have a SB instance anyway, would look more concise to just write one more `append` call, rather than throw concatenation in the mix

Comment: actually Intellij provides the reasoning concerning performance as well: 

Reports String concatenation used as the argument to StringBuffer.append(), StringBuilder.append() or Appendable.append(). Such calls may profitably be turned into chained append calls on the existing StringBuffer/Builder/Appendable, saving the cost of an extra StringBuffer/Builder allocation.
This inspection ignores compile time evaluated String concatenations, which when converted to chained append calls would only worsen performance.

Comment: The append code will be clearer to the humans that have to read your code months or years later, including yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per IntelliJ reasoning:

> Reports String concatenation used as the argument to
> StringBuffer.append(), StringBuilder.append() or Appendable.append().
> Such calls may profitably be turned into chained append calls on the
> existing StringBuffer/Builder/Appendable, saving the cost of an extra
> StringBuffer/Builder allocation. This inspection ignores compile time
> evaluated String concatenations, which when converted to chained
> append calls would only worsen performance.

so, I would say: go for it!

Answer (score 1):

What you've said is correct in the sense that a mixture of concatenation and `StringBuilder` goes against the point of using it in theory, but the extra performance we're talking about is incredibly minimal unless you're loop has a massive number of iterations.

In terms of code clarity I think the double `append` is actually a lot clearer considering you're using it anyway.

I would see the two statements as

```
Append ", " appended on "value"
```

```
Append "value"
Append ", "
```

of which the second actually seems more concise, even if the code is technically longer.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion concatenation is much more readable for developers but StringBuilder.append is performant

Comment: `rgba.append(value).append(", ")` can also be considered as clear as `rgba.append(value + ", ")` (or even clearer IMHO, when I want to *highlight* appending the comma)